# Etymology of "flounder"

Tags: etymology

The Online Etymology Dictionary reads:

> flounder (v.) 
>   1590s, perhaps an alteration of founder (q.v.), influenced by Dutch flodderen "to flop about," or native verbs in fl- expressing clumsy motion.

Thus, the origin of *flounder* is not certain. However, after reading that dictionary entry, I wonder if *flounder* can be simply an embellishment of *founder*, where the sound unit *fl* might be used in order to carry a subliminal meaning of heavy movement, according to [J. R. Firth's theory](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme).

Can this origin be realistically considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following extract The word ***[Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/09/founder-flounder/)*** explains why the two term fonder and flounder are often confused and  comments on their possible  origin. It appears that the noun "flounder" (a fish) and the verb flondev are not etymologically related , but the verb "flounder" is most likely an alteration of to fonder, derived from the assonance with other verbs like "blunder":

> - The matter of “founder” versus “flounder” is exactly the sort of question my parents delighted in exploring, and in their Harper Dictionary of Contemporary Usage (1985), they delivered a concise verdict:  ***“These two verbs are often confused and consequently misused***.  ‘Flounder’ means to ‘thrash about,’ as would an animal mired in mud.  ‘Founder’ means to ‘fail completely, collapse or sink.’…”

The origin of "founder"  is from French "fondrer":

> - To begin at the beginning, the verb “to founder” means, in its basic sense, “to sink completely, collapse,” or, in an extended sense, “to fail utterly.” ***The source of “founder” was the Old French “fondrer,” meaning “submerge, send to the bottom,”*** and its ultimate root is the Latin “fundus,” meaning “bottom” (which also gave us the words “foundation,” “found” and “fundamental,” among others).

while the verb "flounder" probably is an alteration of "fonder" due to its assonance with other verbs:

> - ***“Flounder” as a verb is an odd bird.  (The noun “flounder,” a kind of flat fish, is etymologically unrelated to the verb “to flounder”).***
> - ***The verb “to flounder” is almost certainly an alteration of “to founder,” influenced by other verbs, such as “blunder,” depicting clumsy or frantic motion.*** When “flounder” first appeared in the 16th century, it meant “to stumble,” and later “to struggle clumsily.”  A bit later on, it came to mean “to struggle along with great difficulty.”

But  confusion between the two term persists:

> - The confusion between “founder” and “flounder” arises when the extended figurative uses of the words converge.  If clueless Jim has been promoted to sales manager and can’t handle the job, he may well “flounder” (struggle along) for a few months before he “founders” (fails) completely.  In the example you gave, I would tend to think that “flounder” was actually the proper word, but without knowing the exact wording, it’s hard to be certain.

Answer (score 10):

Well, since the OED says it's of obscure etymology, and may certainly have some sound symbolism, let's take a look at [the `FL-` Assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/fl.pdf).

There are three distinct (but overlapping) semantic characteristics:

1. 46 words -- 2-Dimensional Non-Extended
2. 21 words -- Inadequate
3. 31 words -- (Repeated) Small Motions

And our friend *flounder* is spang in the middle of the Venn diagram, since it is

- a noun representing a fish principally known for being flat,
  and which flops around, as all fish do in air

as well as

- a verb meaning 'to perform repeated small inadequate motions'
  leading to an inadequate performance.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's a bit anthropocentric from the flounder's point of view. In his *own* natural environment (the sea) I'm sure he thinks he swims around quite gracefully and purposefully. Obviously things are a bit different when he's a [fish out of water](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fish-out-of-water.html) At least *lambs* get to gambol around, happy as Larry, before being led to the slaughter. And even pigs get to be happy when they're in shit. But for the poor flounders there don't seem to be any "idiomatic upsides"! :)

Comment: That's a great answer!

Comment: How does one access your list of phonosemantic venn diagrams?

Comment: Here's [a bibliography](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/monobib.pdf). Items 11 & 13 contain or link to all my data, most of which is not Venndiagrammable. If you like phonosemantic Venn diagrams, however, [this one](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) is the killer.

Comment: _Flounder_ is already a troublesome word, for semantic reasons. Fillmore describes [the problem with flounders](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/flounder.html) in his [second Deixis Lecture](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Comment: May I ask what 2-Dimensional Non-Extended means?

Comment: If one says something is "2-Dimensional", it means that it has two prominent dimensions; i.e, it's flat. To say it's "non-extended" means it has edges and doesn't extend off into the distance like the surface of a body of water or ice or a plain, which are also 2-Dimensional.

Answer (score 6):

Even OED says *flounder* is *of obscure etymology*, so I don't think we're going to resolve anything here.

But here's the full text of what they say...

> *Perhaps an onomatopoeic blending of the sound and sense of various earlier words; compare **flounder** v. (Old French **fondrer**), **blunder** n., and the many verbs with initial **fl-** expressing **impetuous and clumsy movements**. Wedgwood and Skeat compare Dutch **flodderen**, to flounder in mire, to flop about: see the dialectal **flodder** v., which may have affected the development of the present word.*

The above-mentioned "initial **fl-**" includes verbs such as *flop, flail, flip, float, flex, flood, flit, flight, flub*, etc. It's easy to see how people might often choose *flounder* over the relatively uncommon *founder* in many contexts - especially if they weren't particularly familiar with either word in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives different sources for the verb *flounder* and the noun (fish) *flounder*. For the verb:

> [prob. alter. of *founder*] (15c)

For the fish:

> [ME, of Scand origin; akin to Norw *flundra* founder]

Somewhat similarly, the *New Oxford American Dictionary* (2001) offers this origin for the verb:

> late 16th cent.: perhaps a blend of FOUNDER [in the sense of "fill with water and sink"] and BLUNDER, or perhaps symbolic, *fl-* frequently beginning words connected with swift or sudden movement.

and this origin for the fish:

> Middle English: from Old French *flondre*, probably of Scandinavian origin and related to Danish *flynder*.

Whether the verb *flounder* is from the 15th century (as Merriam-Webster's says) or from the late 16th century (as Oxford says), it is certainly a younger word in English than the fish *flounder*. That being the case, I wonder whether *flounder* the fish may have influenced the emergence of *flounder* the verb.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting sidenote: *A Dictionary of the English Language*, by Samuel Johnson (1785 edition found on archive.org), gives these interesting definitions:

> *Flounder. [flynder, Danish; fluke, Scottish.]* The name of a small flat
>   fish. Like the flounder, out of the frying-pan into the fire.
>
> *Flounders will both thrive and breed in any pond.*

Not so sure, though, about "fluke", I could have misread it.

> *To Flounder. [from flounce.]* To struggle with violent and irregular
>   motions: as a horse in the mire.
>
> *Down goes at once the horseman and
>   the horse; 
>   That courser stumbles on the fallen steed,  And floundring
>   throws the rider o'er his head*

And, according to Mr. Johnson, *flounce* means:

> Anything sewed to the garment, and hanging loose, so as to swell and
>   shake.

[You can find Johnson's definition on archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryofengl01johnuoft#page/n799/mode/2up)

I hope it helps.